# Check $S\cap T$ where $S =\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x^6 -x^5 \le 100\right\}$ and $T =\left\{x^2-2x : x \in (0,\infty)\right\}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R} : x^6 -x^5 \le 100\right\}$ and $T=\left\{x^2-2x : x \in (0,\infty)\right\}$. Then check whether or not $S\cap T$ is

1. Closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$
2. Closed but not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$
3. Bounded but not closed in $\mathbb{R}$
4. Neither closed nor bounded in $\mathbb{R}$

I know a little bit about closed sets that contain their limit points and about bounded sets which can be enclosed. But here the set $S$ is weird to visualise; it seems difficult to see what elements will be inside $S$ and until we know the elements of the set how can we decide its closure and boundedness?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $T$ you probably know what it is. For $S$ consider polynomial $p(x)=x^6-x^5$.
Since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}p(x)=+\infty$, the set $S$ is bounded...

Let $p(x)=x^6-x^5$. Using derivatives we see that $p(x)$ has only one local extreme: minimum
at $\frac{5}{6}$ where $p(\frac{5}{6})=-\frac{5^5}{6^6}$. On $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\frac{5}{6})$
the function $p(x)$ is decreasing and on $(\frac{5}{6}, \infty)$ it is increasing (at $0$ it
has a saddle point). If follows from this that the curve $y=p(x)$ has two intersections with the *horisontal* line $y=100$, i.e., the equation $x^6-x^5=100$ has two solutions: one has to be somewhere in $(-\infty,0)$, call it $x_1$, and the other, say $x_2$, is on $(\frac{5}{6}, \infty)$. Hence, $x_{1}^{6}-x_{1}^{5}=100$ and $x_{2}^{6}-x_{2}^{5}=100$. For $x_1<x<x_2$ one has $x^6-x^5<100$ and for $x\in (-\infty,x_1)\cup (x_2,\infty)$ one has $x^6-x^5>100$. We conclude that $S=[x_1, x_2]$, a bounded closed interval.